# Data Model for abstracted transactions table that combines more granular transactions

Tags: database-design

A fast food restaurant has an existing sql table of transactions:

`old_transactions`:

| transaction_id | item_description | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | burger patty | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | bun | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | ketchup | 1 | 0.25 |
| 4 | packaging | 1 | 0.50 |
| 5 | labor to make burger | 1 | 1 |

We would like to create an abstraction on top of those transactions. For instance, transactions 1-4 are instead a single transaction for the purchase of one say "Deluxe Burger" for $6.75. In our "abstracted" transactions table, we would not even include the labor to make the burger.

`abstracted_transactions`:

| transaction_id | item_description | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Deluxe Burger | 1 | 6.75 |

This way users can easily query how many Deluxe Burgers were sold and at what price without needing to do the complex logic of piecing it together from the number of burger patties, buns, ketchup etc. were sold. It then would allow us to switch our accounting API to post new transactions in terms of Deluxe Burgers rather than the different pieces and we can fill in and allocate the price between the patty, bun, ketchup differently.

How would you set up the "abstracted" transactions table? It's a 1 to many mapping but where the many can be constituents of the 1? I cannot edit the existing `transactions` table. Aside from adding "constituent number 1", "constituent number 2", etc. columns to the new transactions table, I am not sure how to create a flexible model for more complex relationships like this?

Comment: "It's a 1 to many mapping but where the many can be constituents of the 1?" What do you mean, exactly? Your use case does appear to be a simple one-to-many relationship from a transaction to its constituents, with the addition of a filter on the type of the constituent. It seems you can just create a join table linking a transaction to a constituent along with a type column to fulfill your use case.

Answer (score 1):

### First naive answer

When there is only one finished product and its component products the problem looks simple. But in reality there are many different finished products and some share components (e.g. ketchup is probably used in at least 60% of your burger catalogue).

To cope with this situation you need for each finished product, independently of the transactions, a list that indicates the number of pieces of each component product. This is called a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials).

Then what you need is a mapping between `old_transaction` and `abstract_transaction`.  This looks like a one to many at first sight.  It would then be sufficient to add a column `abstract_id` in `old_transaction` to map many component lines to one finished product line,  using the BOM to either aggregate the lines (finding what to add in abstract),  or decompose the lines (i.e. add a line in `abstract_transactions`,  and generate the corresponding detailed lines in `old_transactions`).

### But is it really that simple?

Your narrative leves a lot of questions open.  If you generate the detailed lines, it's ok as described above!

But if you're aggregating you could have:

| transaction_id | item_description | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | burger patty | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | bun | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | ketchup | 2 | 0.25 |
| 4 | packaging | 2 | 0.50 |
| 5 | labor to make burger | 1.5 | 1 |

and

| transaction_id | item_description | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Deluxe Burger | 1 | 6.75 |
| 2 | Standard Burger | 1 | 5.25 |

Since some components can be shared between several finished products,  you might therefore end up with a many-to-many relation,  i.e. a third table that shows pairs of abstract_transactions and old_transaction,  probably together with the relavant quantities that are mapped.

Finally,  you could wonder if `abstract_transaction` and `old_transactions` are not two faces of the same coin and regroup both in the same table (if needed with a flag indicating if it is an aggregated entry or some of it's sublevel (yes, you could explde a BOM at multiple levels)).

Answer (score 0):

Why would you give a transaction id to labor to make a burger?  Did the customer order one of those?

I realize that this is the situation you find yourself in, but you're going the wrong way around.

It's easy to go from Deluxe Burger to its components, but the other way around is not actually possible in all cases, without guessing.

Ok, maybe guessing is good enough, but you'd have to study the situation to determine what is good enough and how good a job you can do to guess.

You really should encourage capture of the big picture rather than attempting to build it from micro details.  Isn't there another data source that describes what customers actually ordered?  I'd be surprised if there isn't — I'd look around.